# nginx reverse proxy remove subpath on upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an api server I am reverse proxying with nginx. It is functionally working but I want to change the current behavior.

api server url:
http://apiserver:5000/api/v1/ping

the above becomes accessible by this nginx url (see the double 'api' part?):
https://nginxserver/api/api/v1/ping

How can I write the config so that /api hits the api server but without adding an additional 'api' to the nginx url.

```
    location ^~ /api {
        proxy_pass http://apiserver:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /api;
    }
```

Comment: You currently have `proxy_pass` configured to remove `/api` before passing it upstream, which is why you need to add an extra one. Try: `proxy_pass http://apiserver:5000;` without the trailing `/`.

Comment: Thanks, but without the trailing slash I still get the same result. To hit the apiserver from nginx I have to enter /api/api/...

Comment: Did you restart Nginx? Check the configuration using `nginx -t` and `nginx -T` Also, check the access and error logs.

Comment: Yes, I did test and restart - it functions but just with the same behavior. Any /api/ route from gunicorn becomes /api/api/ on gninx.